# javascript array not unique

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Asp.Net user control that I've created. For simplicity some of the html has been removed.

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelInputControl" runat="server" CssClass="input-control input-period">
    <div  ID="InputWrapperMonth" runat="server" class="input-wrapper input-month">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxMonth" runat="server"
            MaxLength="2">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div  ID="InputWrapperYear" runat="server" class="input-wrapper input-year">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxYear" runat="server"
            MaxLength="4">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

I also have a javascript function, that adds classes based on the validity of of the data input. Again I have removed some of the surplus code.

Here's how I build $el:

```
var $el = $(this).closest('.form').find('input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"], select, textarea');
```

Here's the javascript function I call:

```
function updateInputStatus($el) {

    var controls = [];

    $el.each(function () {

        $control = $(this).closest('.input-control');

        if ($.inArray($control, controls) < 0) {
            controls.push($control);
        }
    })
}
```

$el is one or more input controls - textbox, dropdownlist etc. In this example lets say that TextBoxMonth and TextBoxYear are our objects, $el, and the javascript function is triggered.

What I'm trying to do is build an array of unique input-control objects.  In this example PanelInputControl will be found twice, however I only want it to be added to the array once.

Whats actually happening is that the code `$.inArray($control, controls) < 0` always returns -1 whatever the situation (in order words its not being found in the array), and I don't understand why.

I've also tried adding this code at the end, `var cleanArray = $.unique(controls);`, but again the duplicates remain in the array.

I'm confused - any advice?

Comment: `$(element) === $(element)` is false, because those are two different objects, even though they contain the same DOM element. Consider storing actual DOM elements in `controls` instead of their jQuery wrappers.

Comment: I don't understand why `$el` would contain same elements more than once to begin with.

Comment: @juhana - $el wouldn't contain the same element more than once, however in the example they both reference the same parent object which is then duplicated.

Comment: Instead of putting jQuery objects into the array put the bare DOM node.

Comment: if you look at jQuery's documentation on closest, it "constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements" (http://api.jquery.com/closest/) so DCoder is definitively right.

Comment: @DCoder - apologies, but I'm not a javascript coder - please can you clarify, maybe with an example

Comment: Try `$(element)[0] === $(element)[0]`, then thinc about what DCoder said, and understand why he's right

Comment: But `.closest()` already removes duplicates doesn't it? (Certainly seems to here: http://jsfiddle.net/gAQVW/) So you could just say `controls = $el.closest('input-control');`

Comment: @dotnetnoob: There's a distinction between a *DOM Element* and a *jQuery object wrapping that DOM Element*. Almost all jQuery functions return jQuery wrappers instead of raw DOM Elements. It's conceptually quite similar to the [Identity Map pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_map_pattern) problem - without Identity Map, you can fetch the same database record (*DOM Element*) twice and have two separate in-memory representations (*jQuery wrappers*) of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With each loop iteration you create a new jQuery object with:

```
$control = $(this).closest('.input-control');
```

And it is these jQuery objects that you `.push()` into your `controls` array. Even though some of those jQuery objects may contain references to the same DOM elements what you are comparing with `$.inArray()` is the the jQuery objects, which are all distinct objects and so are not duplicates.

The `.closest()` method itself does not return duplicates though, so you could do this:

```
controls = $el.closest('input-control');
```

Then your `controls` variable would be a jQuery object that just has the unique closest `input-control` elements of what was in `$el`.

If you specifically wanted to have `controls` be an array of jQuery objects each of which contains only one `input-control` element, but with no duplicates, you could do this:

```
controls = $.map($el.closest('input-control'), function(v,i) { return $(v); });
```

Comment: Great answer - not something I would have realised in a million years